# Using Google Drive API with PHP to upload images?

Tags: php, api, google-drive-api

I am trying to upload images with the Google API (https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client) and I can't seem to get it working. Whenever I run it it gives me a `401 Login Required` error. Here is my code:

Functions:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->instance = new \Google_Client();

    $this->instance->setApplicationName('DPStatsBot');
    $this->instance->setDeveloperKey(Config::getInstance()->getDriveDeveloperKey());
    $this->instance->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive');

    $this->drive_instance = new \Google_Service_Drive($this->instance);
}

public function upload($image, $dpname)
{
    $file = new \Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
    $file->setTitle($dpname . '_' . RandomString::string());

    $upload = $this->drive_instance->files->insert($file,
    [
        'data' => $image,
        'mimeType' => 'image/jpg',
        'uploadType' => 'media'
    ]);

    return $upload;
}
```

Calls to functions:

```
$client = new DriveClient();

foreach($dm->entities->media as $img)
{
    Printer::write('Recieved image from "' . $dm->sender->screen_name . '", saving to Drive...');

    $client->upload($this->getImage($img->media_url), $dm->sender->screen_name);
}
```

Error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message 'Error c
alling POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=multipar
t&key=APIKEYHERE: (401) Login Required' in C:\Doesp
lay\DPStatsBot\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Http\REST.php:110
```

The API key I am using is from my Google Developers console under `APIs & auth->Credentials` and it is a Public API key.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

**Edit:** `DriveClient` is the class that contains the functions

Comment: read about oauth2. you are not authenticating. and public keys are not for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The public api key is for public access APIs.  Data that is not owned by a user.  You need to create client id from web application.

Then you will be able to authenticate it using Oauth2.

this might get you started.  [drive Quickstart php](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/php)

**How to know when you need to be authenticated:**

- Public API:  [Aanalytics metadata API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/metadata/v3/reference/metadata/columns/list) meta data doesn't belong to any user its public data anyone can access.
- User data API:  [Google Analytics Real-time Data](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/v3/reference/data/realtime/get) the data returned is owned by a user, it is not public data viewable by everyone.  Documentation states

> Requires authorization

If the documentation says requires authentication then you have to be authenticated to access that call.

**File Parent**

Check the $parentId variable, this is how you upload a file into a specific directory if you don't add setParents it will be uploaded into the root folder. [code ripped from](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert)

```
/**
 * Insert new file.
 *
 * @param Google_Service_Drive $service Drive API service instance.
 * @param string $title Title of the file to insert, including the extension.
 * @param string $description Description of the file to insert.
 * @param string $parentId Parent folder's ID.
 * @param string $mimeType MIME type of the file to insert.
 * @param string $filename Filename of the file to insert.
 * @return Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile The file that was inserted. NULL is
 *     returned if an API error occurred.
 */
function insertFile($service, $title, $description, $parentId, $mimeType, $filename) {
  $file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
  $file->setTitle($title);
  $file->setDescription($description);
  $file->setMimeType($mimeType);

  // Set the parent folder.
  if ($parentId != null) {
    $parent = new Google_Service_Drive_ParentReference();
    $parent->setId($parentId);
    $file->setParents(array($parent));
  }

  try {
    $data = file_get_contents($filename);

    $createdFile = $service->files->insert($file, array(
      'data' => $data,
      'mimeType' => $mimeType,
    ));

    // Uncomment the following line to print the File ID
    // print 'File ID: %s' % $createdFile->getId();

    return $createdFile;
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't see this. Once I followed and adapted this it worked! Just one more question, how can I move the file into a directory?

Comment: You cant "Move" a file from one directory to another right now its a bug in the API. You have to download it again and then upload it with the correct parents folder name.

Comment: How would I upload a file into a directory? As far as I know I need to add something to the put fields.

Comment: set the parent as part of the $file before you upload it.   Tip: do a file list to get the parent folder id

Comment: Version note: this code is for V2; function naming in V3 has changed.